# Why was this comment flag on a rude comment declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

I raised a harassment, bigotry, or abuse flag [in a (now deleted) comment in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56457722) with the following content:

> sir i dont care if you believe me or not?! im not here to improve my self to you, second thing if you read my comment well you know its copy past, third thing if you want to answer you can drop it otherwise don't waste your time with fully of drama !have good day

which appeared to be attacking the person it was referencing.

1. > i dont care if you believe me or not
2. > if you read my comment well you know...
3. > if you want to answer you can drop it otherwise don't waste your time with fully of drama

The flag was declined, though, and the comment deleted, perhaps as no longer needed or unfriendly/unkind, which is what I didn't flag the comment, but I don't think I had to.

Comment: It's probably unfriendly, but I don't see any harassment or bigotry or abuse.

Comment: There is a reason we have both "unkind" and "abuse" flags. The comment merits deletion, but it doesn't use abusive language, it's not harassing its recipient, and there is no evidence of bigotry. Tangentially: you made a copy of the comment after flagging it?

Comment: @yivi nope, it was reported by a bot and stored in its server

Comment: @double-beep - did the bot report it as harassment, bigotry or abuse? If that's the case, the bot is a little over-zealous

Comment: @ChrisF it just reported it because it contained some words which were blacklisted and the perspective score was high - the bot works with feedback and is basically to search for rude comments. It doesn't say "this comment should be flagged like...", etc.

Comment: @double-beep: I'm more concerned that you have a bot going around flagging comments like this one.

Comment: @Nicol I believe the bot _reported_ the comment, but the comment was manually flagged by double-beep; as is the case with most of these bots.

Comment: @NicolBolas first of all, the bot isn't mine. Also, enough with it. It just reports stuff in a room - that's all. It has nothing to do with the question and it doesn't autoflag comments.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As [BDL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2579738/bdl) points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385775/why-was-this-comment-flag-on-a-rude-comment-declined#comment701548_385775) the comment is unfriendly but not harassment, bigotry or abuse.

Like spam and rude or abusive flags on posts the "harassment, bigotry or abuse" flag on comments can carry a heavy penalty if followed through. We don't want to hit someone with the full weight of the repercussions of these flags unless their behaviour warrants it.

So in this case I declined the flag, but still deleted the comment.

Unfortunately, if someone else flagged the comment as unfriendly that would have been declined as well as we can't handle comment flags individually.

Please use the most appropriate flag - or, if you feel you have to explain things more clearly than the standard flags convey, use a custom flag.

Comment: _"if someone else flagged the comment as unfriendly that would have been declined as well as we can't handle comment flags individually"_ Sad face. How can we flag the flagging system as unfriendly?

Comment: "Unfortunately, if someone else flagged the comment as unfriendly that would have been declined as well as we can't handle comment flags individually." This line was a little unclear to me, do you mean if someone else flagged the comment as unfriendly in addition to double-beep's r/a flag, that you either have to approve all flags or decline all flags? That's an interesting user experience for the moderators, though I know some mod tools have quirks like that so I'm betting this interpretation is right. Would the same apply if another person used a "No longer needed" or custom flag?

Comment: @DavyM yes. If there are multiple comment flags they have to be handled in the same way. Flags on posts can be handled individually.

Comment: What type of penalty will such a flag carry? As the MSE FAQ says, there is no penalty for a deleted comment.

Comment: @gparyani there's not an automatic penalty, but if you have several comments deleted by the most severe flags it raises another flag and then we investigate to see if there is a pattern. If there is then we can mod message and optionally suspend. I'd rather not have people "accused" of rudeness etc. if it's not warranted.

Comment: Ah, so you'd prefer that the autoflag not trigger in those cases. It's also worth mentioning that declined comment flags don't count toward the flag ban system.

Comment: The "*use a custom flag*" advice is good, especially for if you include explanation and state you're unsure which of the standard flags is most appropriate.  Be prepared to still get declined though with a "Declined - please use a standard flag" despite you saying you didn't know which one to use.  Sometimes that happens and its ok.